# What is difference between Actionchains and Actionclass?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, webdriver

In slenium webdriver with python binding there are two ways you can create action class's object using either Actionchains or Actionbuilder.

If I create an object of Actionbuilder then I can only use some of the methods like perofrm(), but methods like click_and_hold, drag_and_drop are not available with Actionbuilder and only available with Actionchains.

Would there be an instance where you will use just Actionbuilder given the fact all the methods from Actionbuilder are available in Actionchains as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the implementation of the `ActionChains` class [source code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/common/action_chains.py) you would find that `ActionChains` uses the `ActionBuilder` to perform the actions.

ActionChains is a wrapper class that makes it easy to use.

But if you want to build some complex actions yourself that is not in the `ActionChains`, then I guess you could use the `ActionBuilder` and other action classes.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a real-time instance where Actionbuilder was used over actionchains ?